# SSL chain validation failed with intermediate cert

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I want to understand the way the validation chain works. What certs do I really need in my truststore?

I have a chain with
Root CA -> intermediate 1 -> intermediate 2 -> server cert.
I have only the intermediate 2 cert in my truststore. On my one test machine this works all right, but on my other it does not (contacting a different server with similar configuration). I get this popular SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target Exception. The server sends the full chain.
I guess the solution will be to put the whole chain up to Root CA to my truststore.

I want to know why it works on one machine and not the other. Is it possible to have influence on how chain validation works? Can a server require full chain validation?

I could not figure out, if the default truststore from jdk is automatically included or not. The 2 machines have slightly different jdk versions 1.7.0_21 (not working) and 1.7.0_25 (working). Does it matter?

One more thing: this SunCertPathBuilderException - is it possible to find out which part of the chain he does not like?

I am happy for any hints.
Thanks, Heike

Comment: have you compared the keystore on both the servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need the certificate of *any* of the signers in the certificate chain. Typically the topmost one.

I would have a good look at the chain itself as visible from `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` and at the local truststore file to make sure at least one of the certificates in the chain is present with the same signature, date, subjectDN, issuerDN etc as in the debug log.

Comment: In the end it was the chain. You were all right. It really helped me you all telling me there's something wrong with the chain. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You should only need the intermediate certificate. It's more likely to be a problem with the other machine's configuration. You can add `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` to your JVM options to show debugging info.

(More here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug)

Comment: Thanks. Activating the debug log is always my first action. But it does not really help. It prints the server certificate chain and stops at the handshake with this error unknown_certificate. I really double checked that the right intermediate cert is in the truststore - also printed in the ssl debug log. Are you sure it cannot be anything else?

Comment: Can you install 1.7.0_25 in a separate folder and try it?

Comment: Yes I did. But I cannot reproduce it. So, it must be something different. Thanks, so far.

Comment: Try using `jps -v` to check you're running exactly the same JVM options. I once had an obscure certificate error because of a typo in the keystore password.